# How do I make part of the text bold in a cell for an SSIS report?

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a business requirement to make part of the text for a cell to be bold.  It is an SSIS package that is an Excel report.  I don't want to use COM or load Excel.  How do I do that?

Comment: Why are you using SSIS to create a report? It has no ability to format data.

Comment: We have SSIS packages for creating standard reports.  Non standard reports we are using a custom multithreaded C# solution that uses Aspose cells.  We have weird requirements like; tabs with data on them should be colored green.  Just trying to not do another custom report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't format intra cell values in SSIS.  You can format whole cells though by formatting the cells in advance on a template sheet.

Another option, although bad, is to create a macro that the onopen event fires off.